# Retraining HOG in OpenCV Resulting in No Hit

Tags: opencv, detection, svm, training-data

I am currently trying to count car using OpenCV 2.4.4 with HOG descriptor. Because model for car detection is not available in OpenCV (unlike people detector which already have model for the detector), I am creating my own model using SVMLight and dataset of car from INRIA car dataset [here](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/data) (positives and negatives sample).

Then I create the model using the positives and negatives sample with SVMLight (resize the images to 128 * 104 because HOG image must be power of 2), by following [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/trainHOG) tutorial and code. I apply the model to my program, and it detect cars correctly, but also with lot of false positives (3- 8 false positives per image)

I read in Dalal paper of HOG Detector and I found out that the model needs to be retrained using false positives found by applying the preliminary model on the negative samples. The resulting patches comes in varying size, so again, I resize it to 128*104 px.

I rerun the HOG training program using positive and negative samples like the preliminary run, but this time add the false positives on the negative samples (this is what I think of retraining based on the paper by Dalal). Then I have the retrained model.

Unfortunately, I run car detection program using the new model, but all images returned with no car detection although I used positive sample images and other images with car in it.

This is very interesting and I am curious if any of you can point out what have I done wrong. any discussion or question is also appreciated!

I tried the same things, now using pedestrian images. The result is still the same, preliminary model result in lot of false positives. After retraining, the result is no hit (0.0 hit threshold). If I reduce hit threshold to -0.1 to -0.5, the postive images detected, but hit rate is low (50-70%). Well, I guess in the end this is about tradeoff between hit rate and false positives, but still, retraining allows model to be more accurate

**Edit**
After searching in this forum, I think for my system where the camera is static, it is better if I use background segmentation and blob tracking. I am currently not exploring HOG anymore, but for any of you who knows where the problem is in HOG training and detection, maybe you want to post the answer here to help others whom have the same question